# Python - AWS Lambda extract a key from JSON input

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

Im trying to implement a function that will get the event from cloudwatch and print the results. I am able to get the event but I want to extract one particular key from that JSON.

### Here is my function:

```
import json
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2)) 
        message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
        print(message)
```

### The event got from Cloudwatch:

```
"Records": [
{
"EventVersion": "1.0", 
"EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:bhuvi:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
"EventSource": "aws:sns", 
"Sns": {
"SignatureVersion": "1", 
"Timestamp": "2018-01-13T19:18:44.369Z", 
"Signature": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
"SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem", 
"MessageId": "4b76b0ea-5e0f-502f-81ec-e23e03dbaf01", 
"Message": "{\"AlarmName\":\"test\",\"AlarmDescription\":\"test\",\"AWSAccountId\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"NewStateValue\":\"ALARM\",\"NewStateReason\":\"Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [2.6260535333900545 (13/01/18 19:13:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).\",\"StateChangeTime\":\"2018-01-13T19:18:44.312+0000\",\"Region\":\"US East (N. Virginia)\",\"OldStateValue\":\"OK\",\"Trigger\":{\"MetricName\":\"CPUUtilization\",\"Namespace\":\"AWS/RDS\",\"StatisticType\":\"Statistic\",\"Statistic\":\"AVERAGE\",\"Unit\":null,\"Dimensions\":[{\"name\":\"DBInstanceIdentifier\",\"value\":\"myrds\"}],\"Period\":300,\"EvaluationPeriods\":1,\"ComparisonOperator\":\"GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold\",\"Threshold\":1.0,\"TreatMissingData\":\"\",\"EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile\":\"\"}}", 
"MessageAttributes":
{}
, 
"Type": "Notification", 
"UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?xcsgagrgrwgwrg", 
"TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:bhuvi", 
"Subject": "ALARM: \"test\" in US East (N. Virginia)"
}
}
]
}
```

### My extract command(Upto message) and its result:

```
message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
        print(message)
```

**Result**

```
{
    "AlarmName": "test",
    "AlarmDescription": "test",
    "AWSAccountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "NewStateValue": "ALARM",
    "NewStateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [2.6260535333900545 (13/01/18 19:13:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).",
    "StateChangeTime": "2018-01-13T19:18:44.312+0000",
    "Region": "US East (N. Virginia)",
    "OldStateValue": "OK",
    "Trigger": {
        "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace": "AWS/RDS",
        "StatisticType": "Statistic",
        "Statistic": "AVERAGE",
        "Unit": null,
        "Dimensions": [
            {
                "name": "DBInstanceIdentifier",
                "value": "myrds"
            }
        ],
        "Period": 300,
        "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
        "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
        "Threshold": 1,
        "TreatMissingData": "",
        "EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile": ""
    }
```

I want to extract some values from this message pane.

For eg: I want to extract name. So I tried the below command, but unfortunately its not working. Can anyone help me on this? 
[image]

### my code for this:

```
message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']['Trigger']['Dimensions']['name']
    print(message)
```

## ERROR:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      14,
      "lambda_handler",
      "message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']['Trigger']['Dimensions']['name']"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "string indices must be integers"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So there are 3 problems:

**Problem 1:** In your example event, `['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']` is a `str` in JSON format. That means that you need to parse to a dict like this:

```
 message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
 message = json.loads(message)
```

**Problem 2:** `message['Trigger']['Dimensions']` is a `list` but you are trying to access it like if it were a `dict`. So you only need to change your code to:

```
message = message['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]['name']
```

**Problem 3:** `Message` is a `str` that means that you need to verify that is a plain `str` or json str (otherwise you are going to have problems with multiple structures and types). For that your code could look like:

```
 message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    if isinstance(message, str):
        try:
            message = json.loads(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e) # Or do nothing, this is just to log the error
    elif isinstance(message, list):
        message = message[0]
    # Maybe evaluate bool, tuple, etc other types

    print('RESPONSE', message['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]['name'] if isinstance(message, dict) else message)
```

However I would also recommend to make it more extensible iterating the elements that you know are `list`. And for safety reasons (trying to avoid null pointer exceptions), use the `get()` function with a default value. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm . Try maybe to create a function to parse structures and make it reusable.

Good luck!

Comment: Ohhh I think that now I see it, `Message` is a `str` with JSON content (is not a `dict`, it think that the `print` was a little bit confusing). In that case you just need to transform it from json to dict. You can do this:

`import json
message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
print(message['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]['name'])`

Comment: let me try this one.

Comment: Can you do something? can you show me this print?

`print(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'].__class__.__name__)`

Comment: The captured JSON contents are like this, `"Message": "{\"AlarmName\":\"test\"`. Some `"` and `/` characters are there. Was this causing the error?

Comment: No, but check that I'm asking you to print the class name of the object, please try that:

`print(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'].__class__.__name‌​__)`

Comment: sure, give me a moment

Comment: ok, the exception from `json` is not so meaningful. Can you use simplejson? just to test what is wrong (usually it shows more meaningful error messages). You don't need to do as much just, the pip install and import it like this:
`import simplejson as json` and try again to see the error

Comment: I can't install, because it Lambda(serverless from AWS)

Comment: Ohhhh so you are doing it directly from the AWS editor, I thought you were uploading the project. In that case you can't install libraries that's true :S. But this is odd, it should be working, the only thing that I can imagine is that in some cases the `str` is empty or `None`. Ok let's this before applying the `loads`:
`message.replace('\"', '"')`

Comment: So what should I give in message parameter?

Comment: Make something like this:
`message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']` then `message = json.loads(message.replace('\"', '"'))` just give it a try, maybe its having some kind of "extra" escape characters

Comment: Again Im getting the same error  :(  `  "errorMessage": "string indices must be integers"`

Comment: that's weird, after the json loads what is the class of message? I mean:
`print(message.__class__.__name‌​__)` what is returning

Comment: seems json.loads doing something, whenever I gave this im getting this error(even this time too) `  "errorMessage": "No JSON object could be decoded"
`

Comment: can you share the complete code fragment maybe in codepen, gist or something similar as it is (with the changes made), just to test it locally

Comment: Ok, I just took your example event and test it in my AWS Lambda and is working for me. BTW I'm using python 3 (and I didn't do the replace stuff). Can you send me a print of your event (not using the json.dumps that you were doing, pure print(event))

Comment: gits updated with print(event), meanwhile i'll try to execute this with Python 3.6

Comment: I commented your gist with the piece of code that worked for me (using your example event).

Comment: Is this worked on Lambda? I tried 2.7 and 3.6, but no luck :(

Comment: Yes, AWS Lambda with python 3.6 using the example event that you published in gist :S

Comment: Anyhow its works for you, So update this in your answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Now you changed the structure of your event, now `message` is just a plain `str`, evaluate that case. I commented your gist with that solution. Please always verify the structure of your message using the .get() function. Maybe you should create kind of a parser to verify multiple structures

Comment: Awesome, it works like a charm, Can you please update your answer which you mentioned in the Gits, So I'll make it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Just as `Records` is a list, so you use `['Records'][0]['Sns']...`, so is `Dimensions`, so again you need to access the first element.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, can you please give me what should I give in the message parameter?